# How do I straighten out my loop cuts?

Tags: vertices

In the image below all of my loop cut vertices are off track from each other. From a front ortho view they are placed very messy on the faces and are out of line with each other. How do I make them more in line with each other like the above loop cuts?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm understanding is that you'd like to bring the vertices of the back face of your object to be directly behind the corresponding vertices of the front face, down global Y (since you are in Front view)

If the back faces are the same shape as your front faces, and shifted, (not rotated) with respect to the front faces, you can set your snap to *Active* and *Vertex*, select all the vertices you want to move, making a convenient vertex the last selected (and therefore active) and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>
<kbd>Y</kbd> the vertices, snapping the active vertex to its counterpart in XZ.

If not, another possible move -

[image]

Select the back vertices, and (without *Automatic Merge* switched on)   <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> slide them down their edges until they meet their front partners. (You may have to do this in more than one bite). Then  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> them to your required depth.

Or.. it may be more economical to delete the back faces, and make a brand new  extrusion in Y (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>).

It's possible that the result is not the one you're looking for..

Comment: Last solution was perfect. I deleted all the vertices behind the front facing ones and extruded them back on the Y axis. But they looked funky and uneven so I just went to specials>looptools>flatten and locked the XY axes to get the conformity I was looking for. Preciate it.